# Formula from Excel to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, excel, math

**Problem**

I've tried to port this formula directly from Excel. However, the end result is not the same. I'll provide my attempt as well as the right version of Excel. Can someone provide me with the information as to where I've gotten incorrect?

Excel

`=EXP(E3*C7)*0.108*C4*C4/C5*C6/35`

In the next formula

```
E3 = T
C7 = TF
C4 = S
C5 = St
C6 = F
```

Objective-C

```
double exposure = exp((T * TF) * 0.108 * S * S / St * FF / 35);
```

Even

```
double exposure = exp(T * TF) * 0.108 * S * S / St * FF / 35;
```

Returns wrong.

However, the end results aren't the same between them. I've also tried most of the types of exponentials that are offered.

For example, the excel returns 5.2 and objective c returns 5.65.

Comment: You have the `()` different.  `double exposure = exp(T * TF) * 0.108 * S * S / St * FF / 35;` is now the same as `=EXP(E3*C7)*0.108*C4*C4/C5*C6/35`

Comment: EXP in excel returns the entire formula exponentially. I've already tried this.

Comment: EXP in excel is equal to e^ of what ever is in the EXP brackets not the whole formula.

Comment: @gtwebb Initially I had this answer, and the answer was even further away than it is now.

Comment: Have you used a calculator to figure out which one is right?

Comment: @gtwebb I know the excel version is right. About 3-4 years ago I managed to port this into Objective-C. However, there was an error that I eventually found in it to match the Excel formula.

Comment: Try simplifying it and see where the difference is using excel or objective-c [online compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php) I get the same answer for exp(0.2) which makes me think either your variables don't match or something else is wrong.

Comment: @gtwebb try with my Variables to see if you come up with the same. `T = 0.767717 TF = 1.1 S = 20 St = 19.15 FF = 35`  You'll find an answer in Excel of ~ 5.2 and objective-c ~ 4.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward by saying I know absolutely nothing about objective c but using this [compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php) I ran this code which returned 5.248942.  This is the same value I get in excel.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    float T = 0.767717;
    float TF = 1.1;
    float S = 20;
    float St = 19.15;
    float FF = 35;
    double exposure = exp(T * TF) * 0.108 * S * S / St * FF / 35;
   NSLog(@"%f", exposure);
   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

I probably should have used doubles all the way down but there is sufficient precision for these numbers.

Comment: I just ran the same, and got the same in objective-c and numbers.  However the code you suggest could truncate starting at around 10 digits past the decimal.

Comment: So we have the same thing written, with different results. Excuse me whilst I throw my iMac out of the window. Thank You Buddy, I'll struggle on from here as at least I know the formula is right.

Answer (score 1):

Highly probable that you've declared one of those variables as a lower resolution type, for example, as a `float` who's assigned value is getting truncated.

When declared with all `double` inputs, Objective-C and Numbers agree (I can't try excel because I happily don't own a copy).  Inventing values for those variables...

```
double T = 1.1;
double TF = 2.2;
double S = 3.3;
double St = 4.4;
double FF = 5.5;
double exposure = exp(T * TF) * 0.108 * S * S / St * FF / 35.;
NSLog(@"%f", exposure);
// logs 0.472374
```

Numbers, produces the same value from this formula:

[image]

As in...
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it turns out I had an integer for FF.

Comment: @Daniel - That would do it.  As I pointed out in this first-appearing answer that speculated the problem and suggested the fix (`double` operands), anything to the right of the decimal assigned to `FF` would be truncated, generating results slightly less than the excel result.